# Minimizing IO and Memory Usage When Extracting Pages from a PDF

Tags: pdf, itext

I am working on a cloud-hosted web application that needs to serve up extracted pages from a library of larger PDFs.  For example, 5 pages from a 50,000 page PDF that is > 1 GB in size.

To facilitate this, I am using iTextSharp to extract page ranges from the large PDFs using the advised approach found in [this blog article](http://webapplication02.blogspot.com/2012/09/extract-pages-from-pdf-to-new-pdf-using.html).

The trouble I am running into is that during testing, I have found that the PdfReader is reading the *entire* source PDF in order to extract the few pages I need.  I know enough about PDF structure to be dangerous, and I know that resources can be spread around such that random read access all over the file is going to be expected, but I was hoping to avoid the need to read ALL the file content.

I even found several mentions of RandomAccessFileOrArray being the silver bullet to address high memory usage when opening large PDFs, but alas, even when I use that, the source PDF is still being read in it's entirety.

Is there a more efficient method (using iText or otherwise) to access just the content I need from the source PDF in order to extract a few pages?

Comment: Use a `PdfReader` constructor which allows selecting partial mode.

Comment: @mkl I'm using the `PdfReader(RandomAccessFileOrArray raf, byte[] ownerPassword)` constructor, which (according to the source code) defaults to partial mode.

Comment: Then please do post the relevant code. And try to allow access to the PDF. There might be issues on either side.

Comment: I'd be curious if you linearized the PDF in Adobe Acrobat first if that would help you.

Comment: In digging through the iTextSharp code, random access is only supported on files.  To address this, I wrote my own IRandomAccessSource implementation which used the Azure client library to read from the  blob storage.  I am happy to report that it works (I can extract pages from a 1GB PDF and only read 10MB of it) but it still doesn't work as efficiently as I would like.  A REST API may not been an appropriate source for random IO.